# List<dynamic> is not a subtype of Map<String, dynamic> - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to fetch data from server that looks like this:

```
[
  {
   "key": "value",
   "key": "value",
   "key": "value",
   "key": "value",
   "key": [
            "key": "value",
            "key": "value",
          ],
   "key": "value",
   "key": "value",
  }
]
```

My model class has this:
**Update:**

```
List<VehicleDetails> vehicleDetailsFromJson(String str) => List<VehicleDetails>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => VehicleDetails.fromJson(x)));


factory ModelClassName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ModelClassName()
```

My service class has this:**Update:**

```
Future<List<ModelClassName>> fetchDetails() async{
  final response = await get(Uri.parse('$url'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "bearer _accessToken",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },);
  return modelClassFromJson(response.body);
}
```

I'm using FutureBuilder() to get and update my screen

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: fetchDetails(),
            builder: (_, snapshot) {
              print(snapshot.error);
              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
                return Widget();
              else
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );  
            },
          ),
```

The error I'm getting:

> type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'

How can I get through this? Please help.

Comment: The `jsonData` is a `List<Map<String, dyanmic>>` because the JSON response starts with `[`. This indicates that it is a JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes to your `modelClassFromJson` function like

```
ModelClassName modelClassFromJson(String str) {
    final jsonData = json.decode(str);
    return ModelClassName.fromJson(jsonData[0]);
}
```

Comment: After making the above changes I got this: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Comment: @ManishPaul Now the problem occurs in your `ModelClassName` class, check that which variable is Integer and then inside `ModelClassName.fromJson` in `ModelClassName` change the variable assignment to 
`yourIntVariable = json['variableKey'] != null ? int.parse(json['variableKey'].toString()) : 0.0;`

Something like that. (You can do same for any `double` variable like `double.parse(...)'.)

Comment: Hi, please check the above code. I've updated my model and service classes. Though I'm still getting `type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'`

Comment: Can you please show variables of your `VehicleDetails` class?
You need to repeat the same (I have defined in my last comment) in `VehicleDetails` class as well for integer variables.